# Nhibernate - save with smalldatetime field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I have an entity class with datetime field in it:

```
public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

With such mapping (NH 3.2 code mapping):

```
Property(l => l.Date, m =>
{
     m.Column("like_date");
     m.NotNullable(true);
     m.Type(NHibernateUtil.DateTime);
});
```

Column in MS SQL 2005 server is of SmallDatetime type (not nullable).

Problem is when I try to save this object, I get:

System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Date is set correctly to Datetime.Now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out the problem was (as mentioned in other similar questions) not **nullable DateTime** property in class, which was nullable in database. The important part is, it wasn't about the class which I was saving, but other, which was fetched from db in the process.

If you run into such issue, **check other classes too**.